# Terraform provisioner - Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Tags: terraform

I'm unable to fix the issue with file function. The file content is correct and the path is correct too. But I get the following error.

`Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found`

Anything wrong here? Why is it reporting `no key found`?

Here is the code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_south" {
  for_each = {
    prod = "t2.micro"
    dev = "t2.micro"
  }

  ami = "ami-0db0b3ab7df22e366"
  instance_type = each.value
  key_name = "linux-ssh"

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = self.public_ip
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("/home/vagrant/terraform-test/00_test2/linux-ssh")
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${self.public_ip} > public-ip.txt "
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    #content = "foobar"
    source = "public-ip.txt"
    destination = "/tmp/test.txt"
  }


  tags = {
    Name = "web-${each.key}_${local.setup_name}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had downloaded the key pair in PPK format (for putty) and that was the issue.

I created a new key pair and downloaded it as PEM format (for openssh) and then it worked.

If the file did not exist then it would throw the following error:

`Call to function "file" failed: no file exists at`.

But the error `Failed to read ssh private key: no key found` means that the key file content isn't correct.